# button element not removed from print in IE9

Tags: html, css

I have added a print button to my page.

```
<button type="button" class="printBtn">Print This Page</button>
```

And now I want to remove the element from the print.

I used:

```
.printBtn{ display:none;}
```

This works for all other browsers perfectly but for some reason IE does not entirely remove the button when I print the page. The button does not display in print but it messes up the format of my images

example of the images aligned properly not in print preview:
http://i244.photobucket.com/albums/gg5/robasc/Untitled2.png?t=1323881931

example of the images not aligned in print preview and the button is removed using the above css and html:
http://i244.photobucket.com/albums/gg5/robasc/Untitled.png?t=1323881871

I believe the button still exists and is distorting the rest of the elements in the document.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Photobucket is blocked here, so I can't help you =/

Comment: can you pastebin the src in question, makes it hard to diagonse the problem when you can't touch it.

Comment: how about button.printBtn{display:none;} - so add the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using 'onbeforeprint' and jQuery to remove the button from the DOM (a little heavy handed).

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use

```
.printBtn{
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

that hides the butten

Comment: No this still does not work but thanks for the help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: maybe one: try make the `padding:0px;` `width:0px;` and `height:0px;` still a button but its to snall to show...

Comment: wait a minute, it seems as though it's not the button, it's a doctype issue. When I remove the doctype from the document it works fine, but I need a doctype for ie to correctly use my css. This is the doctype I am using?

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: With the doctype added, if I click on print preview on the 1st click it is formatted correctly; however, if I click on print preview a second time without refreshing the page it messes up my formatting. Hhhmmm..

Comment: if you just start making a new website you can think of starting with html5 mutch easyer and for the doctype its than: `<!DOCTYPE html>`, bud i think it messed up your layout becouse you remove them you need to make them invisible i think. if that does not work i don't know sorry:(